# slf4j does not work from a scheduled task thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, log4j, slf4j

I am developing a spring boot application which has a small task configured in a taskexecutor pool.

In the main class i have an slf4j logger and that is able to print the log in the file. But the taskexecutor function and the code inside that does not use the same log file. It is only able to print to console.

```
@ComponentScan("com.poc.poc")
@SpringBootApplication()
public class PocApplication implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    private static final Logger s_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PocApplication.class);

    @PostConstruct
    private void init()
    {
        s_logger.info("In Init");
    }
    @Override
    public void configureTasks (ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        s_logger.trace("In configure Tasks");

        taskRegistrar.addFixedDelayTask(() -> {
        s_logger.trace ("The task caller");
        thetask();
        },60000;
    }

    thetask()
    {
        s_logger.trace ("In the task");
    }
}
```

the log in postcontruct init function is logged in the file.

But NOT the log inside configure tasks, nor the log in thetask() function.

What could be the reason for this and how to make it work ?

I even tried to create a new logger object inside the configuretasks still it does not work

Comment: Do you have `@EnableScheduling` mentioned on any configuration class?

Comment: no it is not enabled. Because i am trying to add a task pool at runtime with some scheduled delay

Comment: Is it possible that the actual logging level is above trace? Try to change trace to info and check if it is logged